# C++ IDEs will not deduce/auto complete member access on std::array subscript expression in template class

Tags: c++, xcode, generics, ide, clion

```
class A {
    class B {
    public:
        int gwe = 0;
    };

    array<B, 3> arr;

public:
    A() {
        arr[0].gwe; // When starting to type 'g', IDE will suggest autocompletion for 'gwe'
    }
};
```

Now if you put on top of that: `template<typename T>`
The IDE will not autocomplete when trying to access a member of the array element.
Let it be Xcode, CLion, I have not tried VS but I am convinced it would also replicate the behaviour.
I have not experienced this before using generics with other languages such as C#, Java or Swift.
So why this has to happen to C++ exactly?

Comment: When you place `template<typename T>` in front of your class definition, you have turned it into a class template. Class templates are *very* different from generics, in that a class template doesn't generate any code. It's a blueprint, and the compiler has no way of deducing *anything* about the class template, until you instantiate it. Visual Studio seems to be the only IDE that supports [Template IntelliSense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/), enabling it to bring autocomplete functionality into class templates.

Comment: @IInspectable I am sorry to disappoint you, but the example I present in my question is true for Visual Studio for Windows as well. Try yourself if you won't believe.

Comment: I just tried with Visual Studio 2019 16.4.0, and Template IntelliSense works as advertised. If you merely turn your class definition into a class template, IntelliSense stops providing suggestions. However, if you pick a type for the template type argument, IntelliSense starts working again. I arbitrarily picked `int` for `T` and after typing `arr[0].` IntelliSense suggested `gwe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing C++ correctly is an extremely complicated and time consuming problem.

If IDEs were to do it perfectly it would take, close to, as much time as compiling the application and you would get annoyed that your IDE was unresponsive.

So, to be responsive, IDEs do limited parsing in finite time, which means they don't always get it right.

Autocomplete and similar features are there to assist/help, but they are *not* the final truth - don't expect them to be.

Comment: *"it would take as much time as compiling the application"* - This is incorrect. You don't need the IDE to emit object code to get proper autocomplete support. You also don't need the IDE to run the optimizer to get proper autocomplete support. The most common reason, why autocomplete fails is because autocomplete uses a *different* compiler front-end than the one they use to produce binary artifacts. And with C++ being as complex as it is, those compiler front-ends rarely agree on everything. This is not about being too costly.

Comment: @IInspectable "This is not about being too costly" - I respectfully disagree. I well know that IDEs use different parsers than the compiler, but I also know that they want to be responsive, and their time to parse very much has an upper limit (in order to stay responsive)..

Comment: IDE's have devised strategies, so that you do not have to pay for the cost of parsing while you are typing. What's more, the scenario described in the question has *nothing* to do with those presumed inaccuracies. The IDE accurately identified a [class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), and stopped providing support, because it *cannot* provide any support. Such is the nature of class (and function) templates.

Answer (score -1):

Not aware about this specific context. However from my experience with other IDE's, I can think of a possibility. Do check whether your IDE version supports autocomplete for C++11 features as std::array is feature which works with c++ 11 onward. 
check whether you need to install additional plugins to enable autocomplete for c++11 features.